# Problemas de upload de archivos php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola gente como andan? Hay algo que me esta rompiendo la cabeza. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
      public function registro(){
  //si presionamos el boton reegistrar.
    if(isset($_POST['registrar'])){
      //VALIDAMOS CAMPOS.
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email' ,'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[usuario.email]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('dni' ,'DNI', 'required|integer|is_unique[usuario.dni]');

      //SI ESTA TODOO OK.
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
      //ACA SE CARGA PLAN ARCHIVO DE PLAN DE ESTUDIO Y BECA
      $this->cargar_archivo();

        //ASIGNAMOS VARIABLES A LOS ARREGLOS DEL TABLE GRUPO FAMILIAR.
          $items1 = ($_POST['nombre']);
          $items2 = ($_POST['apellido']);
          $items3 = ($_POST['vinculo']);
          $items4 = ($_POST['ocupacion']);

          // Estas variables son siempre iguales
          // No tiene sentido definirlas en el ciclo
          $dni = $_POST['dni'];
          $fecha = date("Y-m-d");

          // Recorrer con ciclo for
          for($i = 0; $i < count($items1); $i++) {
              // Usar el mismo índice para acceder a todos los elementos
              $item1 = $items1[$i];
              $item2 = $items2[$i];
              $item3 = $items3[$i];
              $item4 = $items4[$i];

              $rand = rand(1,1000000);
              // Puedes incluir variables en cadenas si están entre comillas dobles
              // Usar el índice para agregar a la cadena
              $nombre = "ingresoFamiliarN°$dni-$fecha-$rand-" . ($i + 1);

              $vinput = "";
              $vinput = 'ingreso' . ($i + 1);
              //POR CADA ITERACION CARGA EN LA BASE DE DATOS EL GRUPO FAMILIAR.
              $this->cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $vinput, $nombre);
        }
  }
```

Dejo la funcion abajo, para que se entienda que es lo que realiza:

```
    private function cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar($item1,$item2,$item3,$item4,$vinput="sin datos",$nombre="sin datos"){
            $mi_imagen = $vinput;
            $config2['upload_path'] = "./uploads/ingresofamiliar/";
            $config2['file_name'] = $nombre . $item1;
            $config2['allowed_types'] = "jpg|pdf|png|docx";
            $config2['max_size'] = "3000";
            $config2['max_width'] = "2000";
            $config2['max_height'] = "2000";
            $this->load->library('upload', $config2);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($mi_imagen)) {
                $archivo = "null";
            }
          $data['datos'] = $this->upload->data();
          $archivo = $data['datos']['file_name'];
          $datafamiliar = array(
            'nombref' => $item1,
            'apellidof' => $item2,
            'vinculo' => $item3,
            'ocupacion' => $item4,
            'ingresos' => $archivo,
            'dni_becario' => $_POST['dni'],
          );
          $this->db->insert('grupo_familiar' , $datafamiliar);
          $data['datos'] = "";
          $archivo="";
      }
```

Y mi base de datos carga dos veces el mismo nombre:

```
ingresoFamiliarN°222222222-2021-05-18-966864_1.docx
```

Cuando en la segunda interaccion deberia de ser lo mismo pero al final `_2.docx`

**EDIT:**
Ahi publique mi function **registro()** completa.

Como verán, despues de validar el furmulario. Tengo la llamada a la función `$this->cargar_archivo();`

Ésta funcion guarda archivos en la carpeta uploads/

La funcion `cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar` la deberia de guardar en uploads/grupofamiliar

Pero algo ocurre que guarda todo en uploads/

No entiendo, si ambas son funciones **private**.

Comment: Borro la respuestas el chico anterior.  Edite la pregunta.

Comment: Puedes imprimir el arreglo `$datafamiliar` antes de `$this->db->insert('grupo_familiar' , $datafamiliar);` para ver que aparece

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco el contexto e indicar dónde ocurre el insert? De todos modos esto huele a un modelo de datos mal diseñado. ¿Qué representa esto exactamente `723231231-2021-05-18-166807` seguido de un número incremental? Veo algo así como una fecha y otras cosas, ¿por qué combinas lo que parecen ser varias columnas en una? Este valor es redundante `723231231` porque está en otra columna y ¿qué ocurre si necesitaras organizar/buscar por fechas? Me atrevo a sugerir que pienses bien tu modelo de datos.

Comment: @JuanRivera no itera una vez. Fijate que edite la pregunta e el echo hace su correspodiente iteracion.

Comment: @MRDev ```array(6) { ["nombref"]=> string(3) "asd" ["apellidof"]=> string(3) "asd" ["vinculo"]=> string(3) "asd" ["ocupacion"]=> string(3) "asd" ["ingresos"]=> string(52) "ingresoFamiliarN°351213132-2021-05-18-231605_1.docx" ["dni_becario"]=> string(9) "351213132" } array(6) { ["nombref"]=> string(2) "22" ["apellidof"]=> string(2) "22" ["vinculo"]=> string(3) "222" ["ocupacion"]=> string(4) "2222" ["ingresos"]=> string(52) "ingresoFamiliarN°351213132-2021-05-18-231605_1.docx" ["dni_becario"]=> string(9) "351213132" }```

Comment: @gisela allí se ve que hasta ese punto el nombre es el mismo, creo que el problema es al subir el archivo y recuperar los datos `$data['datos'] = $this->upload->data();` recupera los datos del anterior. Revisa que guarde ambos archivos.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, es medio complicado lo que hice. 
Es una table en html con inputs name="nombre[]". Es una tabla dinamica, el usuario agrega o quita filas. Por eso el While, y el $items1 = ($_POST['nombre']);

Comment: No es complicado lo que hice, sino, como lo hice xD

Comment: Entonces para que dos archivos no tengan el mismo nombre, pense crear el nombre con un $rand = rand(1,1000000);

Comment: @MRDev Si, evidentemente esta ahí el problema, el tema es solucionarlo ahora jajajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que se ve, tus arreglos tienen la misma cantidad de elementos, por lo que sería más adecuado recorrer con un `for()` o `foreach()` para evitar problemas con los apuntadores y, como ya tienes un índice, lo puedes usar para las operaciones que estás realizando

```
    //ASIGNAMOS VARIABLES A LOS ARREGLOS DEL TABLE GRUPO FAMILIAR.
    $items1 = ($_POST['nombre']);
    $items2 = ($_POST['apellido']);
    $items3 = ($_POST['vinculo']);
    $items4 = ($_POST['ocupacion']);

    // Estas variables son siempre iguales
    // No tiene sentido definirlas en el ciclo
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");

    // Recorrer con ciclo for
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items1); $i++) {
        // Usar el mismo índice para acceder a todos los elementos
        $item1 = $items1[$i];
        $item2 = $items2[$i];
        $item3 = $items3[$i];
        $item4 = $items4[$i];

        $rand = rand(1,1000000);
        // Puedes incluir variables en cadenas si están entre comillas dobles
        // Usar el índice para agregar a la cadena
        $nombre = "ingresoFamiliarN°$dni-$fecha-$rand_" . ($i + 1);

        $vinput = "";
        $vinput = 'ingreso' . ($i + 1);
        //POR CADA ITERACION CARGA EN LA BASE DE DATOS EL GRUPO FAMILIAR.
        $this->cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $vinput, $nombre);
    }
```

Con esto *"matas dos pájaros de un tiro"* porque usas el índice para acceder a cada elemento de los arreglos y para agregar a la cadena aleatoria.

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23379314/2412893) (en ingés), es probable que debas volver a inicializar la librería de carga de archivos para aplicar la configuración:

```
private function cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $vinput = "sin datos", $nombre = "sin datos") {
        $mi_imagen = $vinput;
        $config2['upload_path'] = "./uploads/ingresofamiliar/";
        $config2['file_name'] = $nombre . $item1;
        $config2['allowed_types'] = "jpg|pdf|png|docx";
        $config2['max_size'] = "3000";
        $config2['max_width'] = "2000";
        $config2['max_height'] = "2000";

        // Solo cargar la librería
        $this->load->library('upload');
        // Inicializar para forzar configuración
        $this->upload->initialize($config2);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($mi_imagen)) {
            $archivo = "null";
        }
        $data['datos'] = $this->upload->data();
        $archivo = $data['datos']['file_name'];
        $datafamiliar = array(
            'nombref' => $item1,
            'apellidof' => $item2,
            'vinculo' => $item3,
            'ocupacion' => $item4,
            'ingresos' => $archivo,
            'dni_becario' => $_POST['dni'],
        );
        $this->db->insert('grupo_familiar' , $datafamiliar);
        $data['datos'] = "";
        $archivo="";
  }
```

### Explicación

Desconozco *CodeIgniter* pero quiero suponer que el método `->load()->library()` usa el patrón [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) para devolver solo una instancia de la clase cargada y:

1. Cuando se ejecuta por primera vez, se instancia la clase y aplica la configuración correctamente
2. En llamadas posteriores solo devuelve la instancia creada previamente, conservando la configuración inicial
3. Al ejecutar `$this->upload->initialize($config2);` se está forzando a cargar la nueva configuración

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! Es mas legible. 
Pero sigue poniendo el mismo nombre en la base de datos.

Comment: Ahi edite la publicación

Comment: @Triby al parecer esas funciones son de CodeIgniter

Comment: @MRDev si, es codeigniter.

Comment: @Triby Exacto, era eso! Graciasssssss!!!!!